# Python current time doesn't change when the code is running on a loop

Tags: python

I have a python script that runs a  function every 5 seconds. I noticed that the time output doesn't change when the code is looping. It only changes when i stop the code and run it again. But all the other data in my code is updating every 5 seconds. I don't know what's the condition of the date as i haven't tested it. So when the function is called again its showing the time when it was first executed.  Thanks for your time.

Code

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import time

today = date.today()
now = datetime.now()

def loaddata():

 date1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
 print("d1 =", date1)
  
 current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
 print("Current Time =", current_time)



schedule.every(5).seconds.do(loaddata)

while 1:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What is `schedule`?

Comment: You need to reassign `today` and `now` in the loop.

Comment: And please don't indent Python (or any code) by a single space. It makes it very hard to read.

Comment: Move those variable assignments inside the `loaddata` function.

Comment: @Chris https://pypi.org/project/schedule/

Comment: @Barmar, yeah, maybe. But OP should tell us in the question instead of making us guess (you know this, but it's important for JTC to see it). JTC, please read [ask]. At minimum, you should be `import`ing `schedule` in your code and ideally you should tell us what it is since it isn't part of the standard library.

Comment: You fetch the present day and time only *once* before you start.  Then you schedule a print of those values every five seconds.  Naming a variable `now` does not magically make it update constantly: you have to call `datetime.now()` whenever you want the time updated.  Treat the day similarly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare `today` and `now` in the `fuction`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import time


def loaddata():

 today = date.today()
 now = datetime.now()
 date1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
 print("d1 =", date1)
  
 current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
 print("Current Time =", current_time)



schedule.every(5).seconds.do(loaddata)

while 1:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(1)
```